# Android: Progressbars disappearing from a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-progressbar

I found some similar questions, but could not solve the problem. I have a custom Listview, where each item contains a horizontal progressbar. But when the list contains many items, and I use the scrollbar to navigate through listview, some ProgressBars disappear. What causes this and how do I fix it?

```
public class AdapterMetas extends ArrayAdapter<Metas>{

    private int resource;    
    private Context mContext;

    public AdapterMetas(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.adaptermetas);
        this.resource = R.layout.adaptermetas;          
        mContext = context;     
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Metas p = getItem(position);
        LinearLayout layout = null;         

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(resource, null);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }                   

        int value = p.getiValueMeta();                      

        ProgressBar itemMetaBar = (ProgressBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.itemMetaBar);    

        itemMetaBar.setProgress(value);    

        return layout;
    }


}
```

Comment: I've encountered this before. It's because the ListView recycles views, so any changes to the view you make need to be done with care. Can you post the code that you're using in your adapter to inflate layouts for the list?

Comment: @BDFun I added the custom ArrayAdapter code that fills the listview. how can I prevent the progressbar disappear while scrolling? Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like you're doing the right thing, maybe you're getting a different problem to what I'm thinking. Can you describe what happens as you scroll down? Is there a pattern to the behaviour? When I first tried to do something similar, the changes I was making to the progress bar (i.e. removing it) in each row was affecting other rows, which was due to each row views being recycled. Each time I ran the application and scrolled down, there was a pattern to the rows that were affected.

Comment: @BDFun When I scroll down, I see the other progress bars, but when I back to up, the first bars are no longer visible. So when I scroll back down again, the latest bars are lost too... I guess isn't a good pratice, but I removed the condition `if (convertView == null)` forcing the layout to inflate every time as necessary. While I can't find a proper solution, I have to do this =\ What you think about it? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any code outside of what you've shown that interacts wtih the view or the progress bar? I've just written a test app to test this, and my progress bars do not disappear. It probably doesn't make a difference but any reason why you're using using `getContext()` instead of mContext?

Comment: Hello, has this problem been fixed?